# attempt to drawImage using javascript camgaze.js, real time face detection from webcam --not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, face-detection

I am trying to superimpose an image (mask.png) over a real time video from the webcam using camgaze.js library. (http://aw204.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/camgaze.js/) . SO basically I have just copied the code and I want to modify it according to my need.

The demo for the face detection from webcam is here (http://aw204.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/camgaze.js/examples/face_detection.html).

I am able to replicate the same in my workspace.

Now, I want the mask to be placed when I call the `putMask()` function

```
function PutMask(){

        mask.onload = function() {
        alert('ht' + mask.height)
        alert('width' + mask.width)
        alert('src' + mask.src)
            var width = 640;
            var height = 480;
            var cGaze = new camgaze.Camgaze(width, height, "mirrorcanvas");
            var faceDetector = new camgaze.CVUtil.HaarDetector(
                camgaze.cascades.frontalface,
                width,
                height
            );  //takes classifier name, ImageWidth, ImageHeight

            var drawer = new camgaze.drawing.ImageDrawer();

            var frameOp = function (image_data, video) {
                var faceRects = faceDetector.detectObjects(
                    video,
                    1.1,
                    1
                );

                faceRects.forEach(

                    function (face) {

                       image_data = drawer.drawRectangle(
                            image_data,
                            face,
                            face.width,
                            face.height,
                            3,
                            "red"
                        );

                        context.drawImage(mask,100, 100);   // This line doesnt work                      

                    }
                );

                return image_data;
            };

            cGaze.setFrameOperator(frameOp);  
        } 

        mask.src = "/static/images/mask.png";           
}
```

I am able to see my face marked in a red rectangle which proves that face detection is happening. Also, I am able to get alerts of mask.height and mask.width which proves that the mask image is also loading. but I am not able to draw the mask image on my face using `context.drawImage(mask,100, 100);`.

I want it to be drawn on real time and it should be redrawn on the canvas every time the red rectangle is drawn. So basically the mask should move wherever the face goes.

Please help. Though  I have seen a number of demos on this using Javascript, I find that the code doesn't work, if I copy paste the code base onto my workspace. What is going wrong here. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just fyi: face detection in camgaze.js is based on https://github.com/inspirit/jsfeat which in turn is based on old version of https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect. Also, could you provide more 'context'? A self-contained example for us to have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think context is defined. If you want to mask an image over each face, you should manipulate the image_data object passed in by Camgaze.js, and you should return the augmented image_data. I am pretty sure I added a drawImage method to the ImageDrawer object in Camgaze.js.